# Condition-based subset extraction from both a Pandas Dataframe and a Numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas Dataframe `df` and a numpy array `ar` of the same size. I can extract rows from `df` like this:

```
subdf = df[df['column'] == value]
```

But how can I extract corresponding rows from `ar`, i.e. rows with the same indices?

In my case, `df` is also a subset of bigger Dataframe, meaning that `df.index` is not a set of consecutive integers.

Comment: `ar[df['column'] == value]`

Comment: How about using index values extracted in `subdf` variables to be used for extraction from Numpy Array. For example, if you have an array: `arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])`, we can access the index using `arr[subdf[0]]`. This will access the value in arr using index value in `subdf[0]`.

Comment: Thank you very much Quixotic22. It was so simple. Many thanks to you Gurjot Mahi.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1,2,3,2,1]})
ar = np.array([10,20,30,20,10])
ar[df['value'] == 2]
```

output:

```
array([20, 20])
```

or, if you have higher dimensions:

```
ar = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)
ar[:, df['value'] == 2]
```

input:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

output:

```
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 6,  8],
       [11, 13],
       [16, 18]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so clear but lets make an attempt

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2021-09-14','2021-09-14','2021-09-14','2021-09-13','2021-09-12','2021-09-12','2021-09-11'],
    'Date_Yesterday': ['2021-09-13','2021-09-13','2021-09-13','2021-09-12','2021-09-11','2021-09-11','2021-09-10'],
    'Clicks': [100,100,100,50,10,10,1]
})
df

array=df['Clicks'].values# Array

s=df.loc[3:4, 'Clicks'].index# define dataframe index range
```

or

```
s=df['Clicks'].isin([50,  10])

array[np.r_[s]]#array slice based on df
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. Given the array and dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array(([21, 22, 23], [11, 22, 33], [21, 77, 89]))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=arr, columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3'])
```

If you extract rows from the dataframe, you can use the index from that sub-dataframe to get the corresponding rows from the numpy array.

```
df2 = df[df['c1'] == 21]
arr1 = arr[df2.index]
print(arr1)
```

Output:

```
[[21 22 23]
 [21 77 89]]
```

You can also directly use the same syntax that you used to get the sub-dataframe to get the rows from the array.

```
arr2 = arr[df['c2'] == 21]
print(arr2)
```

Output:

```
[[21 22 23]
 [21 77 89]]
```

Comment: The index version will not work (*df.index is not a set of consecutive integers.*)

Comment: @mozway This seems to work fine if I change it so the index is [0, 2], for example. (See my updated answer where I select the first and last row.)

Comment: But this means you have to `reset_index` on df, create a new dataframe, get the index. Isn't it inefficient compared to direct slicing with booleans?

Comment: @mozway I'm not resetting the index. It is inefficient to create the second dataframe if what you really want is the sub-array, but not if you already have the sub-dataframe, like in the question.